# I can't add more than 2 controls to canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to add controls at run-time for a Windows Phone app but I can't add more than 2 controls to the canvas. I have a textbox in mainscreen, and the user will enter a number which will yield that many textboxes. This code works for 0, 1, or 2 textboxes, but cannot add more than 2:

```
           `int seriuzunlugu;
            seriuzunlugu=Convert.ToInt32(SeriUzunluguTxt.Text);
            int Xtop, Xleft, Ytop, Yleft;
            Xtop = 10;
            Xleft = 70;
            Ytop = 10;
            Yleft = 250;
            for (int i = 0; i <seriuzunlugu ; i++)
            {
                //Xi değeri
                TextBox Xi = new TextBox();
                Xi.Name = "X" + i.ToString();
                Xi.Width = 5;
                Xi.Height = 5;
                canvas.Children.Add(Xi);
                Canvas.SetLeft(Xi,Xleft);
                Canvas.SetTop(Xi,Xtop);
                Xtop = +60;

                //Yi değeri
                TextBox Yi = new TextBox();
                Yi.Name = "Y" + i.ToString();
                Yi.Width = 5;
                Yi.Height = 5;
                canvas.Children.Add(Yi);
                Canvas.SetLeft(Yi, Yleft);
                Canvas.SetTop(Yi, Ytop);
                Ytop = +60;
            }


            //X değeri
            TextBox x = new TextBox();
            x.Name = "xdegeri";
            x.Width = 50;
            x.Height = 10;
            x.Text = canvas.Children.Count.ToString();
            canvas.Children.Add(x);
            Canvas.SetTop(x, Xtop + 50);
            Canvas.SetLeft(x, Xleft);`
```

Comment: In XAML-capable technologies, it is strongly recommended that you use proper XAML to declaratively define the UI, and then proper DataBinding to populate it with actual data. See [ItemsControl](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/)

Comment: I second that, you should try to avoid adding textboxes via code behind when the application is as seemingly straight forward as this and an `ItemsControl` should fit your needs.

Comment: If you want to add "seriuzunlugu" text boxes then you must displace them, they are added, but at the same place... change  Canvas.SetTop(Xi,Xtop); to  Canvas.SetTop(Xi,Xtop + (i * offset));

Comment: Gusman| After adding textboxes I am adding +60 to Xtop value

Comment: @OknAkdgn again, your approach is incorrect, and a Canvas is not an appropriate layout container for what you're trying to achieve here. You're stacking elements below each other in a vertical manner, and that's what a `StackPanel` is for. Use an `ItemsControl` bound to an `ObservableCollection` containing your data items and use proper DataBinding and DataTemplating instead.

Comment: You are right HighCore i get it now thanks for helping